# Prolog Database: Why is program only running once?

Tags: database, prolog

I got this code that has to run a database as long as N > Order.
My code only runs once :/ ?

```
display(N) :-
    w(Order,_,Word,Class),
    N > Order -> (write(Word), write(' '), write(Class)),
    nl, fail .
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you forgot the 'else' branch, and the precedence of (->)/2, that's higher that (,)/2, inhibits the intended order. Try

```
display(N) :-
    w(Order,_,Word,Class),
    ( N > Order -> write(Word), write(' '), write(Class), nl ; true ),
    fail .
```

Comment: You are simply corret! Ofc i just needed that as long as its true statement! thanks alot

Answer (score 4):

your problem is the way you use `->`

First of all, the code is interpreted as:

```
display(N) :-
    (  w(Order,_,Word,Class),
       N > Order ) 
    ) -> 
      (  write(Word), 
         write(' '), 
         write(Class)
      ),
    nl, fail .
```

`->` destroys choice points meaning that it will not try to call `w/3` again.

You could (probably) make it work like this:

```
display(N) :-
    (w(Order,_,Word,Class),
    N > Order )-> (write(Word), write(' '), write(Class)),
    nl, fail .
```

but in the end it's really ugly code and, as you have seen, prone to bugs. A better way is to use `forall/2`:

```
display2(N) :-
    forall(w(Order, _, Word, Class),
           (N > Order ->
           writef("%t %t \n", [Word,Class]); true)).
```

still, this will examine the whole database and print if `N>Order`. It is a bit unclear from your description if this is the desired behaviour but if you want to stop at the first element that is larger you could do something like:

```
display2(N) :-
    catch((forall(w(Order, _, Word, Class),
           (N > Order ->
           writef("%t %t \n", [Word,Class]); throw(end))), end, true)).
```

not the most declarative way to do it but I'm not sure what's the best way to model it without knowing what `w/4` is (I assumed that it is some prolog clauses but it could be a predicate accessing a DB though the ODBC layer)

Comment: Your syntax is invalid.  Only SWI accepts this. For ISO, IF, YAP, B, GNU, SICStus, XSB, Ciao you need extra brackets around (->)/2.

Comment: But still +1 for using forall/2: This is much safer than the original code, where failure gets never detected.

Comment: @false do you mean that you need to write `(A->B;C)`, `A ->(B;C)` or something else? you are right though, I do use swi XD

Comment: `->` appears here in an argument for forall/2. This is invalid like f(a->b). is invalid; the priority must be below 1000. So you need extra round brackets. In case of doubt stick to [GNU Prolog](http://www.gprolog.org/) which supports ISO syntax only (no extension).